# Can I play 1080p HD video on a phone which supports only 720p videos?

Tags: video

I have a phone (Micromax A089) which supports any 720p HD video or movie. But when I try to play any 1080p video then the video runs well but there is no sound.

I am using the latest version of MX Player. I also tried many other players but still got the same result.

Is there any way to play a 1080p video in my phone with the help of an app?

Comment: 1080p video may not be played well because the mobile has limitation. I too face the same problem with some 1080p videos. In my case audio plays very well but video is laggy.

Comment: @MANI Limitations of what sort? Please brief us.

Comment: OP says that mobile only support upto 720p video. Isn't that a limitation? And clearly it's a hardware limitation. I tried almost every video player in Play Store. MX Player alongside Custom Codec also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @MANI I can assume it's a HW limitation but what does that mean? Brief! Besides, [here](http://www.gsmarena.com/micromax_a089_bolt-6418.php) are the specs for the said device. Nowhere I see it can play videos only up to 720p. Another note, OP didn't say "only up to 720p" but simply said "any 720p" (without any evidence; from experience I take it as) which may or may not mean "up to". Regardless, OP also doesn't seem to know what kind of limitation it is or this question might not have been posted. Would you now brief us what do you mean by limitation?

Comment: I would say RAM and GPU. Playing a 1080p videos is like playing real nice games with real nice graphics which requires atleast 1 Gb of RAM and a good GPU unit with great resolution support.

Comment: @MANI Most certainly. There is no way the phone would downscale videos it cannot support. Care to answer this one for us?

Comment: For awhile there i had issues with MXplayer. Try VLC, works like a charm on lower end phones i tested on.  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc hope it works for ya.

Comment: @jer3my Thanks. i will try VLC player and hope it will work. :)

Comment: @Sourav try your luck. Vlc player didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your sound problem is most likely caused by missing the codec needed to play the sound. Try VLC player app.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MX player, their is a button on the top saying 'HW'.
Click on that HW and change it to SW.
This works with me. I have played a 4k video using this setting.
Though it might lag a bit.